# Delete duplicate rows with Active flag false in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with columns "ID", "Name" , "Email" , "Active". I added some duplicate values to the table.

[image]

I want to delete duplicate rows with flag false not all rows with active flag false. In the table I want to delete 2nd row only.

Comment: What happens if there be a name which has two records _both_ of which are false?  Do we delete one of them, and, if so, then what is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below co-related sub-query (Before actual delete, You might want to to see the result using SELECT query)-

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
               WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
                 AND T1.NAME = T2.NAME
                 AND T1.EMAIL = T2.EMAIL
                 AND T1.ACTIVE <> T2.ACTIVE)
  AND UPPER(T1.ACTIVE) = 'FALSE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
DELETE t1 FROM tablename t1 
INNER JOIN tablename t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Email =t2.Email AND t1.Active='FALSE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM users T1
    USING users T2
WHERE  T1.ID <> T2.ID
    AND T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Email = T2.Email
    AND T1.Active = FALSE;
```

---

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c416/6)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    Active BOOLEAN NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO users(Name, Email, Active) VALUES 
('John', 'john.gmail.com', TRUE),
('John', 'john.gmail.com', FALSE),
('Bob', 'bob.gmail.com', FALSE);
```

```
SELECT * FROM users;

DELETE FROM users T1
    USING users T2
WHERE  T1.ID <> T2.ID
    AND T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Email = T2.Email
    AND T1.Active = FALSE;
    
SELECT * FROM users;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM some_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM some_table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
  AND NOT active;
```

Comment: You should describe your solution as it would be more helpful to OP and other users coming across this.

Comment: Have you actually tried your solution? If yes, are you satisfied with the result?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, albeit on the three-row table shown in the question. Would you care to elaborate? I'm assuming the table is denormalized and the same id always goes to the same name and email. If that isn't true, it's easy to extend the `GROUP BY` and use an ad hoc triple `(id, name, email)`.